# Did Biden use 85 cars in a motorcade in Rome?

Tags: united-states, road-vehicles, italy

The [Daily Mail](https://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-10145929/Joe-Biden-blasted-making-10-000-mile-return-trip-Air-Force-One-CLIMATE-CHANGE-summit.html) reports US President Joe Biden's administration used a particularly large motorcade in the streets of Rome recently.

> President Joe Biden was criticized for his use of a slow moving, 85-car motorcade in Rome ahead of UN climate change conference on Sunday

> [...]

> Extra cars were needed as Italy's lockdown rules allow only three non-cohabiting people including the driver to be together in a vehicle

Is this true?

Comment: I don't know this youtube video is a good source for answer  but approximately 75 cars  can be seen  - https://youtu.be/zgDpeKg7u6I

Comment: 85 cars with 2 passengers each sounds rather small for the full Presidential support train including, but not limited to, close protection body guards, crowd management, snipers, counter-terrorism, counter-surveillance, electronic countermeasures, aides, assistants, protocol officers, EMTs, trauma surgeons, tech support for all of the above, etc. especially since I believe at least one of those cars is kept empty as a backup vehicle.

Comment: Isn't the climate change conference in the UK and not in Italy?

Comment: @quarague The points in the story seem to be factually correct but deliberately misleading.  ("Ahead of the UN climate change conference in Italy" can be read as meaning he was in Italy before going to the conference, or he was attending the conference in Italy).